# Use fillna-method per specific segments in dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Currently I have following dataframe, where `F1-F4` are some segments

```
         A    B    C    D   E  F1  F2  F3  F4
06:00    2    4    6    8   1   1   0   0   0
06:15    3    5    7    9 NaN   1   0   0   0
06:30    4    6    8    7   3   1   0   0   0
06:45    1    3    5    7 NaN   1   0   0   0
07:00    2    4    6    8   6   0   1   0   0
07:15    4    4    8    8 NaN   0   1   0   0
---------------------------------------------
20:00    2    4    6   8  NaN   0   0   1   0
20:15    1    2    3   4    5   0   0   1   0
20:30    8    1    5   9  NaN   0   0   1   0
20:45    1    3    5   7  NaN   0   0   0   1
21:00    5    4    6   5    6   0   0   0   1
```

What is the best approach to achieve next dataset after some manipulations?

**E(06:15)** = MEAN( AVG[`E(06:00-06:30)`], AVG[`06:15(A-E)`] ) **#F1==1**

---

**E(20:45)** = MEAN( AVG[`E(20:45-21:00)`], AVG[`20:45(A-E)`] ) **#F4==1**

```
         A    B    C    D   E  F1  F2  F3  F4
06:00    2    4    6    8   1   1   0   0   0
06:15    3    5    7    9 [X0]  1   0   0   0
06:30    4    6    8    7   3   1   0   0   0
06:45    1    3    5    7 [X1]  1   0   0   0
07:00    2    4    6    8   6   0   1   0   0
07:15    4    4    8    8 [X2]  0   1   0   0
---------------------------------------------
20:00    2    4    6   8  [X3]  0   0   1   0
20:15    1    2    3   4    5   0   0   1   0
20:30    8    1    5   9  [X4]  0   0   1   0
20:45    1    3    5   7  [X5]  0   0   0   1
21:00    5    4    6   5    6   0   0   0   1
```

I was trying to use an idea like below, but without success so far

```
In[89]: df.groupby(['F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4'], as_index=False).median()
Out[89]: 
   F1  F2  F3  F4    A    B    C    D    E
0   0   0   0   1  2.0  3.0  2.0  2.0  0.0
1   0   0   1   0  1.5  2.0  3.0  3.5  1.0
2   0   1   0   0  6.0  7.0  6.0  7.0  9.0
3   1   0   0   0  3.0  4.0  3.0  4.0  4.0
```

and now, I am struggling with accessing to values `E==0.0` via key `F4==1`

Comment: The first time you got a pass. This time show your attempt at solving using python/pandas. SO is not a coding service.

Comment: I understand that SO is not coding service, just ask you about new advise - not solution.